# Basins of attraction using Newton-Raphson method for nonlinear system

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, dynamic, complex, nonlinear

I am trying to construct basins of attraction using the newton's method for the system of two equations whose roots are real.  I need to develop a code to get basin of attraction. Unfortunately, my code does not work. Can anyone please help me find the error in my code? I don't understand what exactly the problem is. My code for the basins of attraction is given below:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
r1 = {-1, -1};
r2 = {0, 0};
r3 = {1, 1};

x = Range[-2, 2, 0.02];
y = Range[-2, 2, 0.02];

Xr1 = {}; Xr2 = {}; Xr3 = {}; Xr4 = {};

Do[Do[X0 = {x[[i]], y[[j]]};
X = {x[[i]], y[[j]]};
NoIter = 5;
Do[f = {X[[1]]^3 - X[[2]], X[[2]]^3 - X[[1]]};
 Jf = {{3*X[[1]]^2, -1}, {-1, 3*X[[2]]^2}};
 X = X - Inverse[Jf].f, {NoIter}];
If[Norm[X - r1] < 1 e - 25, Xr1 = Append[Xr1, X0], 
 If[Norm[X - r2] < 1 e - 25, Xr2 = Append[Xr2, X0], 
  If[Norm[X - r3] < 1 e - 25, Xr3 = Append[Xr3, X0], 
   Xr4 = Append[Xr4, X0]]]], {j, Length[y]}], {i, Length[x]}];

ListPlot[{Xr1, Xr2, Xr3, Xr4}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Black},
AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotLegends -> {"r1", "r2", "r3", "r4"}, 
PlotLabel -> 
"Basin of attraction for f(x,y) = x^3-y = 0 and y^3-x=0"]
```

Comment: Change `1 e -25`to `10^-25`!

Comment: And you don't calculate the Jacobian correctly. Just try `Clear[x, y]; D[{x^3 - y  , y^3 - x}, {{x, y}}]` and compare the result to yours.

Comment: I have made these changes, but it doesn't work.

Comment: That should not happen. How did you change your code?

Comment: I changed as below:  Jf = D[{X[[1]]^3 - X[[2]], X[[2]]^3 - X[[1]]}, {{X[[1]], X[[2]]}}];
  X = X - Inverse[Jf].f, {NoIter}];

Comment: …This won't work, of course. `X` in your code is a list of numbers, it cannot be used in `D`. With the code `Clear[x, y]; D[{x^3 - y, y^3 - x}, {{x, y}}]` I'm just showing you the correct expression for the Jacobian. Once again, compare your `Jf` with the output of my code carefully and correct your mistake.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's working now.  I changed it : Jf = {{3*X[[1]]^2, -1}, {-1, 3*X[[2]]^2}};

Comment: The code is working slowly and the number of iterations more than 12 codes it does not work.

Comment: You've made many bad desgin in your code. For example the usage of `Inverse`. Think carefully about the following: do you really need to use `Inverse` again and again?

Comment: …Why do you directly correct the mistake in your original code (and you've only corrected part of it! ) without any clarification? This only makes the post confusing. Please make a bit more effort in editing your question properly. The new question about efficiency in your comment is definitely on-topic, and your question can be *rescued* if you **properly** update your question with this info. (I personally recommend you asking a new question though. )

Answer (score 8):

**modified**

Try

```
xygrid = Flatten[
   Outer[{#1, #2} &, Subdivide[-2, 2, 250 ], Subdivide[-2, 2, 250]], 
   1];
lsg = Table[ {xyi, {x, y} /. 
     FindRoot[{x^3 - y == 0, -x + y^3 == 0}, {{ x, xyi[[1]]}, { y, 
        xyi[[2]]}} , 
      Method -> {"Newton"(*,"StepControl"\[Rule]Automatic*)}, 
      MaxIterations -> 100  ]} , {xyi,  xygrid   }]  ;

fp = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {-1, -1}};
fp1 = Select[lsg, (#[[2]] - fp[[1]]) . (#[[2]] - fp[[1]]) < .001 &];
fp2 = Select[lsg, (#[[2]] - fp[[2]]) . (#[[2]] - fp[[2]]) < .001 &];
fp3 = Select[lsg, (#[[2]] - fp[[3]]) . (#[[2]] - fp[[3]]) < .001 &];

Graphics[{PointSize[Small], Red , Point[fp1[[All, 1]]], Green , 
Point[fp2[[All, 1]]], Blue , Point[fp3[[All, 1]]], FaceForm[Red], 
EdgeForm[Black], Disk[fp[[1]], .05], FaceForm[Green], 
Disk[fp[[2]], .05], FaceForm[Blue], Disk[fp[[3]], .05]}]
```

[image]

**addendum**

Colorize @AlexTrounev`s fine solution approach

```
lsg = Table[{ fp, {pts}} = 
    Reap[FindRoot[{x^3 - y == 0, -x + y^3 == 0}, {{ x, 
        RandomReal[{-2, 2}]}, { y, RandomReal[{-2, 2}]}} , 
      Method -> {"Newton"(*,"StepControl"\[Rule]Automatic*)}, 
      MaxIterations -> 1000, 
      EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[varALL]]] , {10000}];
fixp = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {-1, -1}};
erg = Map[{Values[#[[1]]], Flatten[#[[2]], 1]} &, lsg] // Chop;
fp1 = Select[erg, #[[1]] == fixp[[1]] &][[All, 2]]  // Flatten[#, 1] &;
fp2 = Select[erg, #[[1]] == fixp[[2]] &][[All, 2]]  // Flatten[#, 1] &;
fp3 = Select[erg, #[[1]] == fixp[[3]] &][[All, 2]]  // Flatten[#, 1] &;
Graphics[{PointSize[Small], Lighter[Red], Point[fp1 ], Lighter[Green],
   Point[fp2 ], Lighter[Blue], Point[fp3 ], PointSize[Large], 
  FaceForm[Red], EdgeForm[Black], Disk[fixp[[1]], .1], 
  FaceForm[Green], Disk[fixp[[2]], .1], FaceForm[Blue], 
  Disk[fixp[[3]], .1]}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image]

**addendum 2**

The last plot depends on the plotting order of `fp1,fp2,fp3`, because pixel may overlap because of numerical reasons!

```
list = {{ Red , Point[fp1 ]}, { Green , Point[fp2 ]}, { Blue , 
    Point[fp3 ]}};
GraphicsRow[
 Map[Graphics[{PointSize[.001],Permute[list, #]  , FaceForm[Red], EdgeForm[Black], 
     Disk[fixp[[1]], .1], FaceForm[Green], Disk[fixp[[2]], .1], 
     FaceForm[Blue], Disk[fixp[[3]], .1]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-2 , 2}, {-2, 2}}] &, Permutations[{1, 2, 3}]], 
 ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Your last picture looks very nice (+1). Could you colorize line solution as well?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Sorry to late, you colorized your line plot meanwhile. Modern art!  Just one remark:  The appearanceof the colored point plot isn't unique, it depends on the order of `fp1,fp2,fp3` in the Graphics command! Only my first plot is unique because it only plots the starting point in the fixpoint color.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Your first plot could be unique if you make color transparent using `RGBColor` as in my last plot.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I think my first plot is unique because only one gridpoint ist plotted

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Normally we plot trajectory of dynamic system to visualize basins of attraction, and not first and last points only.  Because every points on trajectory belongs to basin of attraction. In this case we use Newton's iterations as trajectory points.

Comment: @AlexTrounev For numerical reasons pixel may overide each other. Have a look at my second addendum.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Use `PointSize[.001]` to exclude overlapping.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Images are  much better but still different. Probably because finally we use the screen raster

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way is to use `FindRoot` with option `Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> Automatic}` and with random initial points as follows

```
varALL = {x, y}; eqAll = {x^3 - y, y^3 - x};
points := 
 Module[{res, evx}, {res, {evx}} = 
   Reap[FindRoot[Table[eqAll[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqAll]}], 
     Table[{varALL[[i]], RandomReal[{-2, 2}]}, {i, Length[varALL]}], 
     Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> Automatic}, 
     MaxIterations -> 1000, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[varALL]]]; evx]
```

With this code we can generate list of points in Newton's iterations  and plot basins of attraction

```
lst = Table[points, {5000}];
ListPlot[Evaluate[lst], Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False]
```

[image: Figure 1]

We also can use `Line` for visualization as follows

```
varALL = {x, y}; eqAll = {x^3 - y, y^3 - x};
line := Module[{res, evx}, {res, {evx}} = 
   Reap[FindRoot[Table[eqAll[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqAll]}], 
     Table[{varALL[[i]], RandomReal[{-2, 2}]}, {i, Length[varALL]}], 
     Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> Automatic}, 
     MaxIterations -> 1000, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[varALL]]]; 
  Line[evx]]

Graphics[
 Evaluate[
  Table[{RGBColor[RandomReal[{0.4, .7}], RandomReal[{.1, .4}], 
     RandomReal[{.7, 1}], .1], line}, {2000}]], Frame -> False, 
 Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {-2, -2}, AxesStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Figure 2]

To colorize last picture with `RGBColor` we use code

```
lst = Table[point, {2000}];

root0 = Select[lst, Norm[Last[#]] < 10^-6 &];

root1 = Select[lst, Abs[Last[#][[1]] - 1] < 10^-6 &];

rootm1 = Select[lst, Abs[Last[#][[1]] + 1] < 10^-6 &];
Graphics[{{RGBColor[1, 0, 0, .1], 
   Line[rootm1]}, {RGBColor[0, 1, 0, .05], 
   Line[root0]}, {RGBColor[0, 0, 1, .05], Line[root1]}}, 
 Frame -> False, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {-2, -2}, AxesStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Answer (score 5):

From your code I take it, you want to calculate the zeros of the function "f", what is not the same as the "basin of attraction", see below.

To get an idea about the zeros, we first make a contour plot of the 2 components of f:

```
f[{x_, y_}] = {x^3 - y, y^3 - x};
```

[image]

We have 3 zeros: {1,1}, {0,0}, {-1,-1}

To which zero the Newton method will take us depends on the starting point.

We first define a function that gives us a zero belonging to some start point:

```
  zero[fun_, start_] := Module[{invjacobian, pos = start, x, y},
  invjacobian[{x_, y_}] = Inverse[D[fun[{x, y}], {{x, y}}]];
  While[Norm[f[pos]] > 10^-6 , 
   pos = pos - invjacobian[pos] . f[pos]];
  pos]
```

We can try this e.g.:

```
zero[f, {0.5, 0.5}]

{-1., -1.}
```

However, the Newton method can diverge. E.g. with zero[f, {1, 0}] the While command will never stop. We can exploit this to get an idea about the basin of attraction. For this we change the function "zero" to check if it diverges and return a "1" if it does and a "0" otherwise. With this we get:

```
zero1[fun_, start_] := 
 Module[{invjacobian, pos = start, x, y}, 
  invjacobian[{x_, y_}] = Inverse[D[fun[{x, y}], {{x, y}}]]; i = 0;
  While[Norm[f[pos]] > 10^-5 && Norm[pos] < 1000 , 
   pos = pos - invjacobian[pos] . f[pos]];
  If[Norm[pos] < 1000, 1, 0] ]
```

To get an idea about the basin of attraction we apply zero1 to a grid of starting points and visualize the output by an ArrayPlot:

```
basin = Table[zero1[f, #] & [{x, y}], {x, -2, 2, 0.1}, {y, -2, 2, 0.1}];
ArrayPlot[basin]
```

[image]

The basin of attraction is quite complicated.